# jboss7 - How do i get the number of messages in a queue?

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x

I'm trying to use this code:

```
MBeanServer platformMBeanServer = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
            .getPlatformMBeanServer();
platformMBeanServer.getAttribute(new javax.management.ObjectName(
                        "jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=" + QUEUE_NAME),
                        "MessageCount");
```

But I get this error:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss.messaging.destination:service=Queue,name=queue/TestQ
```

I looked all over the web but couldn't find nothing, please help...

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why go through the mbean-server? You can connect to the jboss messaging server and ask how many messages are on the queue.

Comment: I looked into this option, the only way to do it with JMS is to read all the messages from the queue and count them, and this is very expensive if you have a very large queue (which I have).